# Invalid syntax in WHILE loop for MySQL 8.0.26

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running MySQL 8.0.26 inside a Linux container, using Docker.

I am attempting to run a stress test by infinitely selecting data from a table named `employees` in the `employees` database. To attempt this, I am embedding a `SELECT` statement inside of a `WHILE` loop, with a search condition that always returns true.

I am attempting to issue the following query against the MySQL engine, using the MySQL CLI tool.

```sql
WHILE 1=1 DO
  SELECT * FROM employees.employees;
END WHILE;
```

When I run this query, I receive the error message as follows.

> Error invoking remote method 'DB_EXECUTE_CANCELLABLE_QUERY': Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHILE 1=1 DO SELECT * FROM employees.employees; END WHILE' at line 1

According to the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/while.html), I am using the correct syntax. What is wrong with this SQL statement?

- [Docs: MySQL Comparison Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html)
- [Docs: MySQL WHILE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/while.html)

Comment: `while` is only allowed in programming blocks such as stored procedures, functions, and triggers.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. I wish the documentation had mentioned that.

Comment: Feel free to leave an answer, and I will mark it.

Comment: @TrevorSullivan documentation had mentioned that in parent topic: "MySQL supports the IF, CASE, ITERATE, LEAVE LOOP, WHILE, and REPEAT constructs for flow control *within stored programs*"

Comment: Ah yes, I see that now. @astentx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WHILE` statement is only valid inside MySQL stored procedures, functions.